# How to say "You tell me!" in Russian?

Tags: перевод

A: "What happened?"
B: "You tell me!"

Вы скажй?

Comment: Can you explain how do use it in English?  If my guess is right, you would just ask it back: _Что случилось? - Да, что случилось?_

Comment: "A" did something wrong and she knows it, "B" is angry

Comment: _Это у тебя надо спросить!_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Russian if we are angry we can just reply:

> –Что случилось?
>
> –Он/она еще спрашивает! Это ты скажи.

Comment: rather just implying that asker is knowing what actually happened. Similar would be Это у тебя надо спросить!

Answer (score 2):

In Russian, there is an expression "а это ты мне скажи"/"а это вы мне скажите".

Answer (score 2):

No literal translation possible, because there are different answers depending on context. E.g. if that answering person expresses equal confusion, it must be a  an unrelated phrase in Russian with similar meaning, like "Сам не знаю", "А что ты у меня спрашиваешь?", "А черт его знает" etc.

If answer  implies that talking person believes that asking person knows more than them, possible  answers would be closer to English original:

- Ты еще спрашиваешь!                     (you are asking?)
- Ты еще и спрашиваешь!  (empasized form)  (And you *are* asking?)
- Это ты мне скажи, что случилось.  (You tell me what did happen?)
- Это у тебя надо спросить! (You're one who must be questioned)

To situation described in comment, first variant is closest, if B also knows that A related to  event in question. Last two, if B just suspects it and confronts A

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "Я у тебя хотел(а) спросить". It's quite popular answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd translate it as:

> Сами скажите!

Or

> Сам скажи!

"Вы/Ты" instead of "Сами" is acceptable too.

Comment: Никогда не видел чтоб кто-то так говорил, это как-то не по-русски звучит